Open specific URLs in certain app?
How can I tell xdg-open to open, say, YouTube URLs in a specific app, but use my default browser for all other URLs?

The closest you can get with xdg is using url-scheme-handlers, i.e. mailto, http, ftp... and so on.
xdg-settings list default-url-scheme-handlers

This will make Google Chrome the default handler for all https links.
xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler https google-chrome.desktop

You can't achieve domain specificity with xdg-open.Using a script that intercepts YouTube links and opens them with a specific application is really the only way.
This is similar to what you're after.
It's the approach you want, only without the yad dialog. It really depends on how and/or what is opening the URL.

It doesn't have to use xdg-open.

that command doesn't work for me, I need to run something like xdg-settings get default-url-scheme-handler http. xdg-settings version 1.1.3.

@JanKanis The execution, as Geremia noted, doesn't have to be xdg-open.  If you xdg-settings set  default-url-scheme-handler http google-chrome.desktop then any http link will be opened with chrome, regardless of what triggers the URL.  You'd need to be more specific for your use case... What is launching the browser?
